# I need help troubelshotting why my buttons arent being detected properly

Tags: python, pygame

My game is a simple slot game that's based around a numpy grid system and is played with left click to spin and r to reset the board. Im trying to implement a point system to make it more exciting but i cant get the code to detect when im clicking the buttons correctly.

The part of the code that seems to be malfunctioning is the posCheckRight and posCheckLeft functions (close to the bottom part of the code, row 160 - 184). They work correctly sometimes but more than often not, to replicate my issues try clicking nearby the buttons and check the inputs

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import numpy as np
import random as rand
pg.init()

width = 800
height = 800
lineWidth = 15
winLineWidth = 15
boardRows = 4
boardCols = 4
squareSize = 200
space = 55
windowName = "Slots"
windowNameInt = 0
cost = 50
costtxt = "Cost: {}".format(cost)
fontClr = (255,99,71)
player = 1
game_over = False
posCheckLvlR = 0 
posCheckLvlL = 0 

bgColor = (200, 200, 0)
lineColor = (0, 0, 180)
triangleColor = (255, 0, 0)
winLineColor = (220, 220, 220)
circleColor = (239, 231, 200)
crossColor = (66, 66, 66)

screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
pg.display.set_caption(windowName)
screen.fill(bgColor)
board = np.zeros((boardRows, boardCols))

def drawLines() :
    
    #Line 1 vert
    pg.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (0, squareSize), (width, squareSize), lineWidth)
    #Line 2 vert
    pg.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (0, 2 * squareSize), (width, 2 * squareSize), lineWidth)
    #Line 3 vert
    pg.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (0, 3 * squareSize), (width, 3 * squareSize), lineWidth)
    #Line 1 hori
    pg.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (squareSize, 0), (squareSize, height), lineWidth)
    #Line 2 hori
    pg.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (2 * squareSize, 0), (2 * squareSize, height), lineWidth)
    #Line 3 hori
    pg.draw.line(screen, lineColor, (3 * squareSize, 0), (3 * squareSize, height - 60), lineWidth)

def drawPointSyst() :

    #(rightest point)(top point)(bottom point)
    pg.draw.polygon(screen, (triangleColor), ((790, 760), (760, 730), (760, 790)))
    #(leftest point)(top point)(bottom point)
    pg.draw.polygon(screen, (triangleColor), ((720, 760), (750, 730), (750, 790)))
    #temp square
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (triangleColor), (720, 730, 30, 60))
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (triangleColor), (760, 730, 30, 60))


    myFont = pg.font.SysFont(None, 50)
    textSurface = myFont.render(costtxt, True, (fontClr))
    #(x,y)
    screen.blit(textSurface, (560, 750))


snake1 = pg.image.load("snake.png")
snake2 = pg.image.load("blackSnake.png")

def drawShapes():
    for row in range(boardRows):
        for col in range(boardCols):
            if board[row][col] == 1:
                screen.blit(snake2, (int( col * squareSize + squareSize//2 - 32), int( row * squareSize + squareSize//2 - 32)))             
            elif board[row][col] == 2:
                screen.blit(snake1, (int( col * squareSize + squareSize//2 - 32), int( row * squareSize + squareSize//2 - 32)))

def markSquare(row, col):
    shape = rand.randint(1,2)
    board[row][col] = shape

def freeSquare(row, col):
    return board[row][col] == 0

def boardCheck():
    for row in range(boardRows):
        for col in range(boardCols):
            if board[row][col] == 0:
                return False

    return True

def checkWin(player):
    global windowNameInt

    #All vertical
    for col in range(boardCols):
        if board[0][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player and board[3][col] == player:
            vertWinLine(col)
            windowNameInt += 1

    #All horizontal
    for row in range(boardRows):
        if board[row][0] == player and board[row][1] == player and board[row][2] == player and board[row][3] == player:
            horiWinLine(row)
            windowNameInt += 1

    #From bottom right to top left
    if board[3][0] == player and board[2][1] == player and board[1][2] == player and board[0][3] == player:
        drawAscDiagonal()
        windowNameInt += 1

    #From top left to bottom right
    if board[0][0] == player and board[1][1] == player and board[2][2] == player and board[3][3] == player:
        drawDescDiagonal()
        windowNameInt += 1


def vertWinLine(col):
    posX = col * squareSize + squareSize//2
    
    color = winLineColor
    pg.draw.line(screen, color, (posX, 15), (posX, height - 15), lineWidth)
    # print("verti win")

def horiWinLine(row):
    posY = row * squareSize + squareSize//2

    color = winLineColor
    pg.draw.line(screen, color, (15, posY), (width - 15, posY), winLineWidth)
    # print("hori win")

def drawAscDiagonal():

    color = winLineColor
    pg.draw.line(screen, color, (15, height - 15), (width - 15, 15), winLineWidth)
    # print("asc win")

def drawDescDiagonal():

    color = winLineColor
    pg.draw.line(screen, color, (15, 15), (width - 15, height - 15), winLineWidth)
    # print("diag win")

def restart():
    screen.fill(bgColor)
    drawLines()
    drawPointSyst()
    windowName = (str(windowNameInt))
    pg.display.set_caption(windowName)
    for row in range(boardRows):
        for col in range(boardCols):
            board[row][col] = 0

drawLines()
drawPointSyst()

def posCheckLeft(pos) :
    global posCheckLvlL
    for x in pos :
        if posCheckLvlL % 2 == 0 :
            if x > 720 and x < 750 :
                posCheckLvlL += 1
                pass
        elif posCheckLvlL % 2 == 1 :
            if x > 730 and x < 790 :
                posCheckLvlL += 1
                return True 
    return False

def posCheckRight(pos) :
    global posCheckLvlR
    for x in pos :
        if posCheckLvlR % 2 == 0 :
            if x > 760 and x < 790 :
                posCheckLvlR += 1
                pass
        elif posCheckLvlR % 2 == 1 :
            if x > 730 and x < 790 :
                posCheckLvlR += 1
                return True 
    return False


def game() :
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            print(pos)
            if posCheckLeft(pos) :
                print("left")
            if posCheckRight(pos) :
                print("right")

            while not boardCheck() :
                randMouseX = rand.randint(0, width - 1)
                randMouseY = rand.randint(0, height - 1)

                clickedRow = int(randMouseY // squareSize)
                clickedCol = int(randMouseX // squareSize)
                # print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", clickedRow, clickedCol)
                
                if freeSquare(clickedRow, clickedCol) :

                    markSquare(clickedRow, clickedCol)
                    drawShapes()
                        
            checkWin(1)
            checkWin(2)

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_r:
                restart()
                
    pg.display.update()

while True: game()
```

Comment: You really haven't given us much to go on.  When it doesn't work the way you expect, what DOES happen?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to isolate and highlight the problem. Can you create a simpler example that exhibits the problem? What actually is the problem? What does "aren't being detected properly" mean? How do you test the code, what should happen when you do that, and what does happen instead?

Comment: You're doing `for x in pos:`.  Do you realize that `pg.mouse.get_pos()` returns a tuple with `(x,y)`?  Did you really intend to do that processing once for X and once for Y?

Comment: I currently test it by if the posCheckRight function returns true it will print "right" and same for the left. Sometimes when im clicking outside of the buttons designated space it'll still print "right" or "left". Some other times clicking in exactly the same space will result in uncosistent outputs, such as "right, (blank), right, (blank)" even tho i didnt change anything

Comment: because it returns as a tuple i added the posCheckLvlR and posCheckLvlL to try and separate the x and y coordinates, it might be a really stupid solution but its the best i could thing of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check the (x,y) position of the clicks, then you just need to check x and y.  I believe this does what you want:

```
def posCheckLeft(pos) :
    x,y = pos
    return 720 < x < 750 and 730 < y < 790

def posCheckRight(pos) :
    x,y = pos
    return 760 < x < 790 and 730 < y < 790
```